# vtctlclient: command not found

Tags: kubernetes, devops, minikube, vitess

I am trying to run Vitess on Minikube and I'm going through the 'Getting Started' steps found here: http://vitess.io/getting-started/#set-up-google-compute-engine-container-engine-and-cloud-tools

I have installed everything I need to including 'vtctlclient'. I have verified that all the correct directories were created when I did this.

However, there is a script in my directory '/go/src/github.com/youtube/vitess/examples/kubernetes' called 'kvtctl.sh' which uses kubectl to discover the pod name and set up the tunnel and then runs 'vtctlclient'. When I run this script, this is what is returned:

'Starting port forwarding to vtctld...
./kvtctl.sh: line 29: vtctlclient: command not found'

I am totally lost as to why the vtctlclient command is not found because I just installed it using Go.
Any help on this matter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the go install directory is not in your path. Have you tried running vtctlclient manually (just like kvtctl.sh does)?

PS: You may want to join our Vitess Slack channel where you may get more prompt answers for your questions. Let me know if you need an invite.